# If $x$ follows the normal distribution, what's distribution of the vector that contains the same $x$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If $x$ follows the normal distribution, which means that
$$ x \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2).$$
Then, consider the $n\times 1$ vector $\mathbf{x}=(x, x, ..., x)^T$, what's its distribution?

Is it $N(\mathbf{\mu}, \sigma^2I)$?

Comment: No, it's a rank $1$ vector. The covariance matrix is $\sigma^2\mathbf1^T\mathbf1$ (the matrix whose *all* entries equal $\sigma^2$).

Comment: But, the covariance matrix is singular now. There is no inverse of the covariance matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf1_n$ be an $n\times 1$ vector of all-ones.

Then $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ implies that the $n\times 1$ vector $\boldsymbol X=(X,X,\ldots,X)^T$ has a degenerate $n$-variate normal distribution:

$$\boldsymbol X \sim N_n(\mu\mathbf1_n,\sigma^2\mathbf1_n\mathbf1_n^T)$$

So mean of $\boldsymbol X$ is the vector with all entries $\mu$ and dispersion of $\boldsymbol X$ is the matrix with all entries $\sigma^2$.

The distribution is degenerate in the sense that the dispersion matrix is singular, as a result of which there is no density of $\boldsymbol X$.

Comment: Well, no density in $\Bbb R^n$, but there is in a $1$-dimensional subspace (comprising two [rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#Ray)), which is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$.